# Opendaylight : Extending DLUX GUI feature - Unable to install bundle mvn:com.sample.dlux/sampleapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: apache-karaf, opendaylight

All, 
    I am unable to install my custom bundle which has a new DLUX GUI feature. Here are the steps i have done,

1. Downloaded and Started pre-built opendaylight Carbon SR1
2. Created a new maven project with "dlux-archetype"

" *mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.dlux -DarchetypeArtifactId=dlux-app -DarchetypeVersion=0.7.0-SNAPSHOT* "

3. Without modifying any, did "mvn clean install" of this project
4. Then tried to install the newly built bundle using,

   " *bundle:install  mvn:com.sample.dlux/sampleapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT* "

**Error in console,**

Bundle IDs:
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
        Unable to install bundle mvn:com.sample.dlux/sampleapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT

**Error in Log file**

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact com.sample.dlux:sampleapp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sample.dlux:sampleapp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in defaultlocal (file:/home/user1/distribution-karaf-0.6.1-Carbon/system/)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:661)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:576)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:550)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.Connection.getInputStream(Connection.java:123)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BundleInstall.begin(BundleInstall.java:56)

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
    <packaging>pom</packaging> 
    <groupId>com.sample.dlux</groupId> 
    <artifactId>sampleapps</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <prerequisites> 
        <maven>3.0</maven> 
    </prerequisites> 
    <properties> 
         <osgi.core.version>5.0.0</osgi.core.version> 
         <apache.felix.compendium>1.4.0</apache.felix.compendium> 
         <dlux.loader.version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</dlux.loader.version> 
    </properties> 
  <modules> 
    <module>sampleapp-module</module> 
    <module>sampleapp-bundle</module> 
</modules>
</project>
```

**sampleapp-bundle - pom.xml**

```
          <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>sampleapps</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.sample.dlux</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>sampleapps-bundle</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>${osgi.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>${osgi.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.felix.compendium}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opendaylight.dlux</groupId>
        <artifactId>loader</artifactId>
        <version>${dlux.loader.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.dlux</groupId>
        <artifactId>sampleapps-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>target/generated-resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <!--loader Resources-->
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-loader-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</outputDirectory>
                        <groupId>com.sample.dlux</groupId>
                        <includeArtifactIds>sampleapps-module</includeArtifactIds>
                        <excludes>META-INF\/**,*/node\/**,*/node_modules\/**</excludes>
                        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        <ignorePermissions>false</ignorePermissions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>org.osgi.service.http,
                        org.osgi.framework;version="1.0.0",
                        org.opendaylight.dlux.loader
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package></Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

May i know where i am going wrong?.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

"Could not find artifact com.sample.dlux:sampleapp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT" means that the bundle's artifact(jar) is not available in the local maven repository.

Try to verify that the jar exists in the .m2 folder manually (check that the artifactId, the groupId and the version are correct).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already checked and the *.jar is not there. As per maven archetype, it will create the following artifacts under "sampleapp" project

     sampleapp
         |-pom.xml 
         |-sampleapp-bundle  
         |-sampleapp-module 

but there is a  jar in sampleapp-bundle directory in .m2 ..i also tries to install that but that too fails with same error.

Comment: What is the groupId:artifactId:version of your bundle ? check the pom.xml file

Comment: <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <groupId>com.sample.dlux</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleapps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <properties>
        <osgi.core.version>5.0.0</osgi.core.version>
        <apache.felix.compendium>1.4.0</apache.felix.compendium>
        <dlux.loader.version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</dlux.loader.version>
    </properties>
  <modules>
    <module>sampleapp-module</module>
    <module>sampleapp-bundle</module>
  </modules>

Comment: This is the pom of the parent project. So please share the pom of bundle "sampleapp-bundle". Thanks

Comment: I have updated my question with them pom file of sampleapp-bundle . thanks again

Comment: In the sampleapp-bundle - pom.xml, update the parent artifactId from tasks to sampleapps. Then build your project (mvn clean install). Then try to install the bundle into Karaf : bundle:install mvn:com.sample.dlux/tasks-bundle/1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @SNivas if you tried my solution, thanks to share a feedback. :)

Comment: Karim, as you said it due to wrong path. Though the .jar files are present in .m2 directory, this application was looking in another path. so i manually copied there and it is working now.. Now there is another issue, more particular to opendaylight i think..

Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Unable to execute command on bundle 452: The bundle "com.sample.dlux.sample-bundle_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT [452]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.opendaylight.dlux.loader; version="[0.6.0,1.0.0)"

Comment: this package must be provided by your Karaf at runtime. Install the org.opendaylight.dlux dependency into Karaf. If this jar is not OSGi ready, install it using wrap protocol (bundle:install -s wrap:mvn:.....)

Comment: You can also try to install the jar file directly without maven. 
bundle:install file:///dir_to_jar/your_jar_file.jar